# Download large PDF in javascript

Tags: javascript, download

I have a website which hosts large PDF documents, as well as some other file formats.

How can I open up a download-dialog box in javascript so that the user can save the document to their computer?

Comment: Why do you need Javascript for this? Why not use a normal link with `target="_blank"`?

Comment: I need the user to download it as opening it in a new window causes the browser to timeout as some of these PDFs are quite large. Firefox for example, returns "Stopped" when trying to download some of the larger files.

Comment: Don't you already use `content-disposition` attachment header that basically tells the browser that it should download the file?

Answer (score 0):

PDF always needs download (even for iframe / embed /object ) so do not use those as its then potential double overload on server, once to downlink and show then potentially a second time by the scripting (However if user selects the "save download as" button in viewer the download should be just once)

The answer is display a small image or icon to show the download content, then back that up with

`<a href="file.pdf" download="filename.pdf"><Img src="cover.png"></a>`

something like this:-

[image]

```html
<a href="https://africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf" download="A Sample.pdf"><img src="https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/download-pdf-icon-png-icon-29.png" width="128" height="128"><a><br>right click icon to chose download options
```

note clicking the icon may show a blank page based on browser security, that is normal, hence the suggestion the user uses their discretion.

[image]